# Query column with object datatype

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to do a pandas query when the datatype is object? I tried:

```
df.query('Train.Test=="Test"')
```

And also

```
df.query('Train.Test==Test')
```

without success.

```
SampleID,Age,Ctrl.Case,Train.Test,Subject.ID
2241944,22,Ctrl,Train,1
2119485,22,Ctrl,Test,2
2312486,21,Ctrl,Test,5
2813487,19,Ctrl,Test,6
2812488,21,Ctrl,Test,7
```

Should I convert it to string first? or can I still query with `Train.Test` as object type?

Comment: You will need to do boolean indexing, the `query` method will not work due to the dot(period) in the column name.  Try: `df[df['Train.Test'] == 'Test']`

Comment: that is due to the column name

Answer (score 3):

Any column name that is not a valid Python variable name needs to be quoted with a pair of back ticks:

```py
df.query("`Train.Test` == 'Test'")
```

Comment: Or backtick it!  Nice @CodeDifferent I forget about this option. +1

Comment: square-brackets, quotes nothing a backtick. didnt occurred to me :)  +1